# Gparted won't let me resize an EXT4 partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'd like to make a partition (200GB) in order to dual-boot Ubuntu with Kali-Linux. Here is my harddrive `/dev/nvme0n1` :

[image]

I don't have a lot a experience to partition a drive, and I don't want to damage that one. Could anyone be able to explain to me how is it possible to do this?

**EDIT :**

Is there a way to resize an allocated EXT4 partition?

I know I could use `resize2fs` resize an unallocated partition, but here it is risky. Is there any options I could use with this command to avoid lost informations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 4):

Unlike NTFS partitions, EXT4 partitions cannot be "hot-resized". This means you cannot resize the partition while you are booted from it.

---

You will need to boot from a live USB stick or DVD to resize it.

1. Once you have done that, open Gparted, and right-click on your main partition. Select <kbd>Resize/Move</kbd> from the context menu.
2. From that screen, you can enter a new size for the partition in MB.

   Since you want to make a 200GB partition for Ubuntu, you will need to enter the new size as the current size in MB, minus 204800. Once you have done that, click the <kbd>Resize/Move</kbd> on that same screen.
3. You will then need to click the <kbd>Apply All Operations</kbd> (the green check mark) button on the main screen.

Once the operation completes, you should have some unallocated space after your main EXT4 partition.

---

During the Ubuntu installation, make sure to select the <kbd>Something Else</kbd> button on the "Where do you want to install Ubuntu?" screen. Format the unallocated space as EXT4, and set it's mount point as `/`.

Finally, make sure to set the location for the installation of GRUB as `/dev/nvme0n1`.

Then you can proceed with the installation as normal.

Comment: I'll suggest putting 200gb in the "free space following" box while on resize dialog who seems more user fiendly to me. Maybe little off-topic but I'll also suggest trying running Kali from a VM (they have specific downloads https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/ ) making a _cleaner and portable solution (better than usb+persistence for some cases)_.

Comment: @dgonzalez What do you mean by "putting 200GB in the "free space following" box "? Can you write an answer taking into account what you say (if it's worth it)?

Comment: I wrote an answer but it was practically the same as yours and when I went to publish it yours was already there. I do not think it's worth a new answer, just a screenshot like the following I think explains the previous comment http://gparted-livecd.tuxfamily.org/larry/resize/big/resize-1-mouse-b.gif